# InAppWebView onLoadStop triggers twice?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to detect if user tries to click the search icon in the mobile Wikipedia website:
`https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#/search`. The `InAppWebView` should detect this and show an `AlertDialog` and go back to the previous page (in this case: `https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`)

My problem is that for some reason the `AlertDialog` appears twice (causing the user to close down two `AlertDialog`s consecutively to have access to the app again).

Ideally what I would've liked to happen is for the `AlertDialog` to only appear once on click of the Search icon then go back to the previous page.

I currently have this:

```dart
InAppWebView(
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(startPageUrl)),
          onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = true;
            });
          },
          onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
            if (url.toString().contains('#/search') && !isLoading) {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                        content: const Text('You can`t use search!'),
                        actions: <Widget> [
                          TextButton(
                            child: const Text('OK'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              // TODO should go back to previous page
                            },
                          )
                        ]
                    );
                  }
              );
            }
          },
          onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
            if (progress == 100) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
            }
          },
      ),
```